# extract parameter from response

Tags: php, curl

I am getting this string from CURL response

```
{status: 'false',description:'5400'}
```

I want to extract description parameter only. 
I want $description = 5400 ;

How to do this ?

Comment: Is your json response with proper header? Can I see the code where you generate it?

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: https://ideone.com/F6U4Uc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bad json response, you have to change your json code and than using the following code you can access the variable.

```
<?php
$response = '{"status":false,"description":5400}';
$response_array = json_decode($response);
echo $response_array->description;
?>
```

And if you want to get the value of description with the existing bad json, you can do following thing.

```
<?php
$response = "{status:'false',description:'5400'}";
$r = explode("description:'", $response);
$description = rtrim($r[1],"'}");
echo $description;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

That response is json. Turn it into a PHP array:

```
$response = "{status: 'false',description:'5400'}";
$response_array = json_decode($response, true);
$description = $response_array['description'];
echo $description;
```

Answer (score 0):

@ [Nirali Joshi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1511197/nirali-joshi)

If Your JSON with space then it will be write solution

$response = "{status : 'false', description : '5400'}";

$response = str_replace(" ","",$response);

OR

$response = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $response);

$t_repsonse = explode("description:", $response);

$i_description = str_replace("}","",str_replace("'","",$t_repsonse [ 1 ] ));

OR

$i_description = str_replace("}","",preg_replace('([ "\' ])', '', $t_repsonse [ 1 ]));

$description = $i_description;

Sorry and improve if any mistake founds and thanks